# What color swatch is this?

Tags: color, inkscape, swatches

Trying to figure out how to load the swatch pictured in the below image in Inkscape:

[image]

Comment: Which swatch exactly are you talking about?

Comment: It seems like you just need the RGB values so you can recreate the exact color, right?  If that's the case then http://alternativeto.net/software/digitalcolor-meter/?platform=linux would be a good place to start.

Comment: I actually think that swatch is pretty cool ... I like the numbering concept for the colors - for example theres yellow-100, yellow-200, etc.  I could just pause the video and use a sampler to grab the colors, but ideally I would be able to import the swatch somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe those are Google's 'Material Design' colors...

[image: Material Design Swatches in Inkscape]

You can download the swatches for use in Inkscape and Gimp here:

https://github.com/KiSSFLOW/gimp-material-design-color-palette

And for Photoshop and Illustrator here:

https://material.io/guidelines/resources/color-palettes.html